# Cannot upload files with javascript code on webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

The objective is to automize a process with Task Scheduler and to upload a file to a webpage. I have identified the part of the code where the process is failing.
The javascript code l have is:

```
// We wait for the button "Send Invitations" appears on the webpage
await page.waitForSelector('input[name=commit]', {visible: true});  

// Upload the archive DIAS_ATRASO
fileInput = await page.$('input[type="file"]');
await fileInput.uploadFile(archivoDiasAtraso); 

// Wait 7 minutes for the archive to upload 
await page.waitFor(420000);
```

Relevant const and vars:

```
var archivoDiasAtraso = filePath + 'XX_XX_XX_' + currentDate + '.zip';

const filePath = 'C:/Users/name/Documents/X/XX/';
```

The code in the browser is the following:
[browser code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G8LL.png)

```
 input multiple="multiple" type="file" name="upload[file][]" id="upload_file"
```

There is one other button on the same page which looks like the following:

```
input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send Invitations" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
```

I do not know what has changed and I cannot identify what exactly is the problem. If you need more information, please let me know. I hope someone can help me with this.
Thank you!

Comment: any error information that you can add?

Comment: The way that I know its not working is that the automatization process stops, however it works manually. I dont know where an error message/information would be, do you have a tip for how to get that information?